# Which probability formula do I use?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

If the probability of discovering a new planet within the next 1,000 years is 0.99, what is the probability that we will discover a new planet within the next 200 years?

Note: that each discovery of a planet is independent of each other.

I want to use the Poisson process formula, but I don't think that is correct since the probability is given out of 1000 trials, and we are solving for 200 trials.

Comment: I believe that the exponential distribution might be better suited for this task.

Comment: Is the question finding at least one or exactly one?  In either case use Poisson, with parameter depending on above answer.

Comment: The actual numbers are quite different.  Since 1992 the discovery rate has been about 150 exoplanets per year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant at least $1$ in $1000$ years, then you could use an exponential distribution for finding none, which  is $0.01$ for $1000$ years. Therefore for $200$ years the probability for finding none is the fifth root, which is equal to $0.3981,$ so the probability of finding at least one in $200$ years is $0.6019.$